# DENIED by fallthru

Tags: git, configuration, gitolite

i have this problem :

I am using :

```
running gitolite3 v3.6.6-6-g7c8f0ab on git 1.8.3.1
```

edited the gitolite.conf :

```
repo tester
   RW+           =  user1
   RW+  sandbox/ =  user2
```

According to my understanding :

- user1 - can do everything against repository tester
- user2 - can do everything(pull/push/rewind/delete) *only* against branch *sandbox* of repository tester

In practic, i created from user1 the branch sandbox, added some data, pushed and tracked it on remote, on user2 i checkedout the branch sandbox, pulled the data, edited some file and when i tried to push the modified file:

```
remote: FATAL: W refs/heads/sandbox tester testgit DENIED by fallthru
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/sandbox
```

Eventually i had to "- master =  user2" and give right to user2 to RW+ over all repo after to obtain the right to pull/push/delete only on branch sandbox(aswell on any other branches...)  in gitolite.conf.

My question is why isn`t it working out of the box with the "sandbox/" branch limiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [refex field](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#refex) is "a regex that matches a ref".

I don't think `sandbox/` would match a branch.
`sandbox` would.
Or `sandbox$` to restrict to the exact name '`sandbox`'.

Comment: To be more specific mr. VonC : fromg itolite all-in-one : http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#access-control-rule-matching look on chapter "2.3.4.1 what does a rule look like?" ...and on image from right we notice clearly : "RW+ dev/                =   dilbert @devteam" => dilbert and @devteam can do anything to branches whose names start with "dev/". This is what i failed to accomplish with my sandbox/

Comment: @Mr'Black that is for all branches starting with `dev/` (`dev/xxx`). In your case, if you have a branch named '`sandbox`' (not `sandbox/xxx`), try the refex `sandbox`.